# String to list of pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input like this:

```py
x = '415,252,428,233,428,214,394,207,383,205,390,195'
```

And I want to end up with this

```py
y = [(415,252),(428,233),(428,214),(394,207),(383,205),(390,195)]
```

The closes I got is

```py
tmp = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')]
y = zip(tmp[::2], tmp[1::2])
```

How do I get rid of the intermediate list? I need alternative to `[::2]` that could be used on a generator.

Comment: Maybe you can use `chunked` or `sliced` from the [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To reduce memory usage you can exploit the mechanics of `zip` and `iter` / iterator / generator expression.

1. Make `tmp` an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

   You can achieve this by changing the brackets from `[]` to `()`; changing it from a list comprehension to a generator expression.

   You can alternately wrap the list comprehension in an `iter` call. However that would still be using \$O(n)\$ memory.
2. In case you don't know what an iterator is, than it's a very useful [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).

   In short the iterator contains in it some data, and a single method to get the next bit of information. In Python the `next` function calls this method.

   Take the iterator a list provides:

   ```py
   >>> my_data = iter([1, 2, 3, 4])
   >>> next(my_data)
   1
   >>> next(my_data)
   2
   ```
3. If you think of zip in terms of iterators, then you'll notice that with two input it works something like:

   ```py
   def zip(a, b):
       while True:
           yield next(a), next(b)
   ```

   This means if `a` and `b` are the same then zip will get the first value and second value in a tuple. Then it will get the third and fourth, until it gets all values.

And so to improve memory usage you can change your code to:

```py
tmp = (int(i) for i in x.split(','))
y = zip(tmp, tmp)
```

**Note**: this still runs in \$O(n)\$ space, as `x.split()` also makes an intermediary list. However it has cut the code from four intermediary lists to just one.

---

This is a common pattern, as provided in the [`itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

> ```py
> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
>     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
>     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
>     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
>     return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
> ```

```py
y = grouper((int(i) for i in x.split(',')), 2)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it works that way. It makes sense, but I find this very counterintuitive

Comment: May because you still think of `tmp` as a sequence, that's the mistake I made.